# Shortcut for getting an item from a returned array at particular index/key?

Tags: php

I feel like there is some way of doing this with a shortcut:

```
$date_array = explode("-", $date);
$day = $date_array[2];
```

Something like:

```
$day = explode("-", $date)[2];
```

Basically getting the answer and setting it to something?

Can't remember, but aren't there a bunch of fancy "=" things like `.=` concatenation. Are there other shortcuts like that? Can't seem to find an article on Google with all the shortcuts.

I hate having to make a `$date_array` when all I honestly want is the `$day`, makes me feel like my code isn't efficient.

EDIT: Changed the title to be more universal, can't think of anything great.

Comment: As far as I know, doing the `[2]` after an explode in PHP is invalid. Though it would be nice if that would work.

Comment: PHP 5.4 supports array dereferencing like that.

Comment: @Adam184 As the title it would probably be clearer calling it 'Shortcut for getting an item from a returned array at particular index/key?' - just a suggestion. The use of the word 'Output' twice in the title is confusing imo.

Comment: changed, yeah the original title was very confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [new features in PHP 5.4 page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) says, the syntax you suggest (known as function array dereferencing) is now possible as of that version.

```
$day = explode("-", $date)[2];
```

This will not work, however, in 5.3  or before.

Comment: LOL I thought you were being sarcastic, until I plugged this into a new PHP file. thank you!

Comment: @lonesomeday Ah... just goes to show I haven't worked with an up-to-date server for a while ;)

Answer (score 5):

### List out the variables

`list(,,$day) = explode("-", $date);`

`list()` takes an array and parses it in to variables... you can skip the items you don't want by leaving the item blank as i've done above. Should do what you need. The other type of syntax you were trying wont work in php *(at least not the versions I've ever used)* - that's more of a JavaScript type notation.

### Alternative

Just in case you were interested there is another solution to what you're attempting *(unless it was just an example to illustrate)*:

```
/// this will give you the current day based on server time
$day = date('d');

/// this will work from an existing Y-m-d date
$day = date('d', strtotime($date));
```

Now whether converting a Y-m-d date string to a timestamp is quicker than splitting a string and listing out it's vars - only a speed test would tell *(I would think the split would win)*. But for me the above is nicer because I can't help thinking about the other array items that were split out and then just lost to oblivion ;)

Comment: thanks! do you know of any other equal sign shortcuts like `.=`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'equals sign shortcuts'. the list of operators can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php and what you want is probably http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php - the only ones I've every really used would be `.=` `+=` and `&=`

Comment: thanks for the link, it was exactly what I needed to hear. The alternate solution is nice, but I was looking for a universal fix I could use everywhere :)

Comment: @Adam184 heh yeah no worries, was more of a light-hearted item for the future existence of this question :)

Answer (score 0):

After php5.4 you could do this:

```
$day = explode("-", $date)[2];
```

Before php5.4, you could use `list`.

```
list(,,$day) = explode("-", $date);
```